# Full stops in project name bad practise?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

Would it be classed as bad practise to have a solution called "Importer" and then have several projects called Importer.[projectname]

Imagine project name is like Importer.Model etc.

Is that good or not?

I want to confirm my thoughts with other developers

Thanks

Comment: I dont think its bad practice but would it not be a bit redundant, if your solution is called Importer then surely every project within that solution would have a name like Importer.Something

Comment: @Purplegoldfish Not necessarily. It's rather common for some rather huge solutions to contain more than one root namespace.

Comment: Maybe this can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481697/net-best-practices-guidelines-for-dividing-namespaces-between-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not bad practice, as long as you choose appropriate names.

Visual Studio will assume that the project name provides the default namespace, so for a project named `Foo.Bar` you'll have `Foo.Bar` as your namespace.

This is useful when you're working on a set of libraries that fit under a parent namespace. For example, you might want to use your company name as the first part of the namespace, and the library name for the latter part, e.g. `MyCorp.MailLib`, `MyCorp.ReportsLib`, etc.

Comment: Assume, until you specifically change it. ;) Not to mention the third component - assembly name.

Comment: Sure, but I'd argue that having the project name equal to the project's base namespace is a good thing to do. It means that you can easily identify the project from the namespace name, and (as long as you don't rename it!) the binary too.

Comment: Aye. But it's not enforced. =) Then again. This -is- a discussion about "practice".