# Organizing namespaces and classes in directories

Tags: c#, code-organization, namespaces

When I put a class file inside a folder, Resharper suggest me to update the namespace. So if I have the file `Classes/Game.cs` (Class), it will suggest the namespace `MyApplication.Classes`.

The problem is that I have a subfolder called `Game` too, that have components for the `Game` class. And it is confliting with namespaces. For instance:

```
/Classes/Game.cs                   MyApplication.Classes.{Game}
/Classes/Game/Version.cs           MyApplication.Classes.Game.{Version}
```

What is the best method to turn around that?

Currently I'm organizing like that:

```
/Classes/Game/Game.cs              MyApplication.Classes.Game.{Class}
/Classes/Game/Player.cs            MyApplication.Classes.Game.{Player}
/Classes/Game/Version/Version.cs   MyApplication.Classes.Game.Version.{Class}
/Classes/Game/Version/History.cs   MyApplication.Classes.Game.Version.{History}
```

So note that I rename the "main" class to `Class` to avoid conflict, but I keep a more accurate name in the filename. But it is ugly, not?

Comment: The real question is *why* do you have these subfolders at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, a folder named "Classes" doesn't seem particularly helpful - everything is a class after all and this doesn't seem to give you any useful information.

If you wish to keep this naming scheme, then there are two options. The first is to disable Resharper's recommendations - or at least tell R# to treat them as Hints, rather than Warnings.

The second is to give your folder a name that isn't a valid namespace declaration. This will make R# stop suggesting it as a valid namespace. The format I've most often seen and used is to use square brackets around the name. So you have a folder hierarchy like this:

```
/Classes/Game.cs
/Classes/[Game]/Version.cs
```

etc. In this case, R# will suggest "MyApplication.Classes" as the namespace for both the Game and Version classes.

Answer (score 3):

Start with this answer to [NET: Best Practices/guidelines for dividing namespaces between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481786/1964861)

While every project, even every game, is going to vary as far as structure goes there are a few things that help.

The first thing you should ask is how large of a project this is going to be. If you don't know, start with everything in the root namespace of your project until you figure it out, and only then refactor. Don't waste time organizing when you could be learning, because chances are you either won't need it, or will need to radically change it once you do figure it out.

Once you know that your project is going to be large enough to require lots of namespace, you should also know what kind of structure it needs. If it's [entity-component oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system), as most large games are now, you'll probably want to use a folder/namespace structure like

```
MyProjectName                          # System classes, like Game1
             .Components               # Base component definitions
                        .Controllers
                        .Physics
                        .Renderers
             .Entities                 # Base entity definition and player entity
                      .Enemies
                      .Powerups
    ...
```

It also helps to work on *other people's code*. You'll learn a lot about organization from trying to locate functionality in unfamiliar code.

Answer (score 1):

My strategy for organizing files is to put them not only inside of namespaces but often in subfolders that don't act as a namespace but help to organize files. I prefix such folders with an underscore `_`. If you're using `R#` you should set the folder property `Namespace Provider` to `false`. Also remember to remove the `_Folder` from the namespace if you add new file because Visual Studio automatically adds it.

Here's an example:

```
MyProject
    Properties
    References
    _Impl
    App.config
    package.config
```

First I put the entire implementation inside the `_Impl` folder because I don't like files that are scattered all around the project.

Next in the `_Impl` folder I may use more underscore `_` folders if I see no reason to create a new namespace but it would make sense to put the files together like `_Exceptions` or `_Enums` or `_Attributes`:

```
MyProject
    Properties
    References
    _Impl
        _Attributes
           MyAttribute.cs
        _Exceptions
            MyExtpion.cs
            MyAnotherException.cs
        _Extensions
            MyExtensions1.cs
            MyExtensions2.cs
        SomeClass.cs
        SomeOtherClass.cs
    App.config
    package.config
```

As namespaces the underscore `_` folders wouldn't make much sense but they allow to keep files together for organizational purposes.

Otherwise I would look something like this:

```
MyProject
    Properties
    References
    MyAttribute.cs
    MyExtpion.cs
    MyAnotherException.cs
    App.config
    package.config
    SomeClass.cs
    SomeOtherClass.cs
```

In `MyProject.Test` with unit test I also use this system:

```
MyProject.Tests
    Properties
    References
    _Impl // only tests
        _Attributes
           MyAttributeTests.cs
        _Exceptions
            MyExtpionTests.cs
            MyAnotherExceptionTests.cs
        SomeClassTests.cs
        SomeOtherClassTests.cs
    _TestHelpers // here I'll put any supporting classes
        SomeTestHelper.        
    App.config
    package.config
```